# WCF: Attempting to set up Two-way mutual SSL Authentication with self-signed certificates and 'PeerTrust'

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I am attempting to setup a WCF service and client on the same machine with mutual SSL authentication.

I have:

- Created certificates for the server and client and put these in the LocalMachine certificate store. The server and clients private keys are in the 'Personal' store, while the public keys are in the 'Trusted People' store.
- I have configured a WCF service and client with each specifying their own certificate reference from the store, and also setting the other parties certificate reference to be validated using

`<authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />`

Note: The server certificates are issued to the Machine name, and the service url called by the client is 'https:\tokenservice\tokenservice.svc

With this configuration I am expecting the client to securely connect to the service with either end resolving the certificates from the 'Trusted People' store, but I am getting the following error which suggests the certificate validation failed:

[AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.]

So this isn't really working as I expected. Can anyone point any errors out? Or are my expectations incorrect?

WCF configuration below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CertificateForClient">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"
                              trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN='ServerCertificate which is machine name'"
            storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TokenService.TokenService" behaviorConfiguration="CertificateBehaviour">
        <endpoint contract="TokenService.ITokenService"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
            binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://tokenservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Client configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientBehaviour">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" findValue="CN=TokenClient"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"></authentication>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ClientBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://tokenservice/TokenService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehaviour"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientBinding"
    contract="TokenService.ITokenService" name="ToolClient">
    <identity>
      <dns value="MachineName" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'd love to see how you were able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The built in authorization provided by PeerTrust and ChainTrust does not work when the authentication is done at the transport layer using mutual SSL.

And to be honest PeerTrust in many cases does not give the control over the authorization process needed.

A very common way to solve this is by plugging in a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager and override its OnAccess method.

```
<behavior name="ServerCertificateBehavior">
  <serviceCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate ....  />
  </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyCustomCertificateAuthorizationManager, MyWCFExtensions.Security" />
</behavior>
```

The ServiceAuthorizationManager can be done in a couple of lines of code for a very static simple certificate check or a more complex based on the needs.

This simple proof-of-concept hopefully can help you get started:

```
public class MyCustomCertificateAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{

    public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext, ref Message message)
    {
        base.CheckAccess(operationContext, ref message);
        string action = operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;

        List<string> approvedActions = new List<string> 
        { 
            "http://kramerica.lan/namespace/MySpecialMethod",
            "http://kramerica.lan/namespace/AnotherMethod"
        };

        List<string> approvedThumbprints = new List<string> 
        { 
            "‎1aaffe105b31b79b66c31de3389203d42351683a",
            "‎f1bcfbc6383bcbfa736473bcaf109987bbc2121a"
        };


        //One way is do the authorization based on the action if the endpoint is used for more than one operation with different ACL needs
        if (approvedActions.Contains(action))
        {
            foreach (ClaimSet claimSet in OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets)
            {
                X509CertificateClaimSet certificateClaimSet = claimSet as X509CertificateClaimSet;
                if (certificateClaimSet != null)
                {
                    //Get the actual certificate used by the client
                    X509Certificate2 certificate = certificateClaimSet.X509Certificate;

                    //Here a real validation of certificate issuer chain etc. could be made
                    if (certificate != null)
                    {
                        //This proof-of-concept does authorization based on a static list of thumbprints but about anything os possible here.
                        //One could easily check if this certificate
                        //is present in the TrustedPeople store or some database backend
                        if (approvedThumbprints.Contains(certificate.Thumbprint))
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The base URL of the service should be the server certificate name.

For example:

> If my server certificate name was test.cer then my service URL should
>   be https://test/MyService/MyService.svc.

Is this how you set up your service?